# Getting Insecure world writable dir when running rails s or rails -v

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, ruby-on-rails-3.2, zsh

I've been following the [Ruby On Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) and tried to get rid of the need for `bundle exec..` by following [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZ-b9oZpCZY&feature=plcp) tutorial video.

However, now when I try to run a command like `rails s` or `rails server`. I'm getting this error.

```
/Users/Keva161/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:211: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/Keva161/Documents/Web Design in PATH, mode 040777
/Users/Keva161/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:211: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/Keva161/Documents/Web Design in PATH, mode 040777
```

Does anyone know what this error is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/Users/Keva161/Documents/Web Design` is indeed world-writeable, and is in your PATH; that means anyone with access to your system can place untrusted programs/scripts there and you run the risk of accidentally running them. From the first part of the screencast (I stopped watching when he started talking about Guard), I don't see anything that would have caused this; the closest thing was the `chmod` command, but I don't see how even a reasonable mistyping could have modified your `Web Design` directory.

Regardless of that, the fix is to change the permissions of that directory so it's not world-writeable, and optionally take it out of your `PATH`, depending on whether you actually need it there. A simple `chmod o-w "/Users/Keva161/Documents/Web Design"` should suffice for the former, but you might want to add `-R` right after `chmod` to apply it to all directories under that one. For taking it out of your `PATH`, I assume you know how to do it in your zsh config file (I don't use zsh so I won't give you a bash answer assuming it will still apply).